# Moving data from nodejs console to SQL Server

Tags: node.js, sql-server-2008

I am very new to node.js. Using the following code I am able to retrive data from the wesbite intrino into console.

```
var https = require("https");

var username = "********";
var password = "********";
var auth = "Basic " + new Buffer(username + ':' + 
password).toString('base64');

var request = https.request({
method: "GET",
host: "api.intrinio.com",
path: "/companies?ticker=AAPL",
headers: {
    "Authorization": auth
}
}, function (response) {
var json = "";
response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    json += chunk;
});
response.on('end', function () {
    var company = JSON.parse(json);
    console.log(company);
});
});

request.end();
```

And the result is as follows:-

[image: Retrieved data]

My question is: how do I transfer this data into SQL Server? I tried watching a few tutorials and videos. But I was not able to exactly understand how it works.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question. Connecting MS-SQL server from node usually uses [tedious](https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious) package. You can directly use this package to insert data as described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/node-js/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-node-js

Following is a snippet from the above link.

```
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;  
    var config = {  
        userName: 'yourusername',  
        password: 'yourpassword',  
        server: 'yourserver.database.windows.net',  
        // If you are on Azure SQL Database, you need these next options.  
        options: {encrypt: true, database: 'AdventureWorks'}  
    };  
    var connection = new Connection(config);  
    connection.on('connect', function(err) {  
        // If no error, then good to proceed.  
        console.log("Connected");  
        executeStatement1();  
    });  

    var Request = require('tedious').Request  
    var TYPES = require('tedious').TYPES;  

    function executeStatement1() {  
        request = new Request("INSERT SalesLT.Product (Name, ProductNumber, StandardCost, ListPrice, SellStartDate) OUTPUT INSERTED.ProductID VALUES (@Name, @Number, @Cost, @Price, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);", function(err) {  
         if (err) {  
            console.log(err);}  
        });  
        request.addParameter('Name', TYPES.NVarChar,'SQL Server Express 2014');  
        request.addParameter('Number', TYPES.NVarChar , 'SQLEXPRESS2014');  
        request.addParameter('Cost', TYPES.Int, 11);  
        request.addParameter('Price', TYPES.Int,11);  
        request.on('row', function(columns) {  
            columns.forEach(function(column) {  
              if (column.value === null) {  
                console.log('NULL');  
              } else {  
                console.log("Product id of inserted item is " + column.value);  
              }  
            });  
        });       
        connection.execSql(request);  
    }
```

But using an ORM is the best practice. [sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/installation/getting-started) is one of the best in the node community.

```
$ npm install --save sequelize
$ npm install --save tedious // MSSQL

const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'mssql'
});
```

You must go through either of these modules documentation to understand better.